# Block outbound on 80,443 except Windows Updates on Windows Server 2019

Tags: networking, windows-update, port, windows-firewall, windows-server-2019

I can't believe I didn't find a proper solution for this problem, which I assume to be quite common:

We have some Windows Server 2019 machines in the network, which are SQL-Server, frequented by different RDP users. There is nothing I can change about this.

Some of the RDP users seem to browse the web from the database machines, which of course shouldn't happen. Maybe they search for help for SQL queries, maybe they forget where they are and even browse Facebook, doesn't matter, it shouldn't happen.

**Therefore I want to block outbound connections on 80 and 443 for these machines. But Windows Updates still need to work.** (*This should be done on the machines' own firewall, not the gateway firewall.*)

So there seem to be two possibilities, with respective disadvantages:

1. Block outbound on ports 80,443 and allow the Windows Update server's IPs explicitly in another rule. Disadvantage: The long list of possible Windows Update server domains might change DNS entries and the Windows Firewall only allows to designate IPs or IP ranges.
2. Block outbound on ports 80,443 and allow the Windows Update process explicitly in another rule. Disadvantage: Unclear which process does what about the Windows Update. Are there different processes? What does Windows Firewall's warning about "not working as expected because of service hardening" mean? I find it hard to find reliable information about this part.

What is the best practice regarding this problem?

Comment: Do you have WSUS? If not, is it an option to use it?

Comment: "What is the best practice regarding this problem?" - You should be using a group policy to specifically not allow IE to be launched.  I would test this policy on a client machine to verify it won't interfere with Windows Update.

Comment: @DanielB We only have a hand full of Windows Servers, that's why nobody did this yet. Thank you for this possible solution.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you for this advice, I will try to solve it this way.